# Where to begin when making a GUI with Java (is Swing deprecated?)

Tags: java, android, swing, user-interface, desktop

I have been learning Java for about 2 years now (on and off) but have stuck to text-based programming, and have never done anything useful with it. I have wanted to mess around with GUIs for a while - at least just to see how you build a small app - and recently began learning how to do so with Swing, but have noticed a lot of stuff online that says Swing is old and/or deprecated (but also a lot of stuff saying the opposite).

Is it worth me continuing with Swing or is there another practise I should become familiar with? I also read that Swing is not transferable to Android - if that is so, is there any benefit to me learning desktop GUIs?

Comment: For discussion and guidance, seek a forums site such as [Java Ranch](https://javaranch.com/).

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to create Desktop Apps, you can check out [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/) (former JavaFX and successor of Swing) or even SWT if you feel more like techy eclipse-like applications.

If you want to go mobile you can create a web app e.g. with Spring Boot + Angular that can run directly in the browser and can be called from both desktop and mobile devices. In this case, your UI would be built with HTML + JavaScript or TypeScript + CSS while only your back end would remain in Java.

Another interesting choice for Webapps with shared Java code for front end and back end can be [Google Web Toolkit](http://www.gwtproject.org/), but this would be hard to recommend since the project seems to be less maintained lately.

Another option are frameworks like [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) with which you can create apps both for iOS and Android which is most likely what you are looking for if you aim for multi-platform mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop GUI using Java, i recommend you [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/). This is open source and very powerfull framework. I worked with it for a long time, there are a lot of documentation, it has large community and there are many integration options (Spring, graphs and so on). It is also easy to make simple vaadin project.

Comment: To be clear, Vaadin is for web apps while the question asked about desktop & mobile apps.